# Does a sequence of distribution converges if it converges on a dense subset of test function space?

Tags: distribution-theory

1. Suppose $\{K_n\} \subset \mathcal{D}'$, and $\langle K_n, u\rangle$ converges for every $u$ in a dense subset of $C_0^\infty$, does $K_n$ converges to some $K\in \mathcal{D}'$?

If this is not true, how about:

2. Suppose $\{K_n\} \subset \mathcal{D}', K \in \mathcal{D}'$, and $\langle K_n, u\rangle \to \langle K, u\rangle$, for every $u$ in a dense subset of $C^\infty_0$, does $K_n$ converges to $K$?

A proof or a counterexample would be appreciated.

Comment: I would start by trying to prove that $\langle K_n,u\rangle$ is a Cauchy sequence for any $u\in C_0^\infty$. It is natural to approximate $u$ by some $\{u_k\}$ in your dense set, but then you need some sort of uniformity to be able to take limits simultaneously in $n$ and $k$. Question: what do you mean by dense in $C_0^\infty$? Do you mean in the sense of the sup. norm of derivatives? Is any assumption on the convergence of the supports made? I am saying this because convergence in $\mathcal{D}$ involves a uniform control on the support  and is thus stronger than convergence in $C_0^\infty$..

Comment: @GReyes  It is dense with respect to the countable family of semi-norms $\{\sup_{|x|\leq N} |\partial^\alpha u(x)|\}_{\alpha, N}$.

Comment: @GReyes what kind of uniformity can we use here? I'm not familiar with the techniques in distribution theory. So far I have tried using the Banach-Steinhaus theorem (in Frechet space) to show equicontinuity of $K_n$: for every $u\in C_0^\infty$, take a sequence $\{u_k\}$ in the dense set convergent to $u$, for every $\epsilon >0$, there exists $N$, for all $k\geq N$, and for all $n$, $|\langle K_n, u_k\rangle|<\epsilon$. This uniformity would work. However, since we only have boundedness on a subset of $C_0^\infty$, which is not a Frechet space, cannot apply Banach-Steinhaus theorem.